# Multisite: How to define and limit a Custom Post Type to specific sites?

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite

I have 2 sites on a Multisite network:

A) Primary.com
B) Secondary.com

The primary site has a custom post type called, "primary_site_employees." I do not want the Secondary site to have access to the "primary_site_employees" custom post type. (The Secondary employees do not work at the Primary.)

I'm prepared to create a new custom post type called, "secondary_site_employees."

How can I have custom post types show up only on a specific site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened when you activated the CPT plugins on each site?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Both sites currently share "primary_site_employees." But I don't want Secondary site to have access to that CPT.

Comment: Honestly, I don’t quite understand the situation. Could you please update your question and explain it a little bit more?

Comment: How are you declaring the CPT?  If it's in a plugin, make sure it isn't network activated.

Comment: ok I updated the question.

Comment: @hereswhatidid - ok, I feel stupid. I'm declaring inside functions.php of the parent theme (which both sites require). I will remove from parent theme's function.php and declare in 2 separate child themes for 2 separate sites. Or just wrap into a plugin and be done. Thanks

Comment: It's probably best to put the CPT declaration into a plugin; the rule of thumb I use is if something affects the site's functionality, use a plugin; if it affects the site's appearance, put it in the theme.